# Proving a combinatorial identity without double counting

Tags: combinatorics, expectation

Consider the following problem:

> We have a collection of *m* white and *n* black balls. We pick *k* balls (*k* ≤ *m*+*n*) **without** replacement. What is the expected number of white balls in the sample?

**Counting method 1:** The ratio of white balls in the collection is *m*/(*m*+*n*). If we repeatedly sample the collection, we expect that on average, our sample has the same ratio. Therefore, the expected number of white balls in a sample of size *k* is *km*/(*m*+*n*).

```
As a side note, I think the above argument somehow depends on the unbiasedness of 
the mean estimator. Am I right?
```

**Counting method 2:** We directly compute the expected number of white balls in the sample:

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k} i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}}{\binom{m+n}{k}} \enspace.$$

---

So, we reach at the identity:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k} i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i} = \frac{km}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{k} \enspace.$$

> How to prove the above result without double counting?
>
> It seems to be provable using [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) as well as $i\binom{m}{i} = m\binom{m-1}{i-1}$. But is there a simpler approach (which does not depend on extra identities such as Vandermonde's)?

Comment: Presumably we are picking without replacement. Your expression is right. For a more formal but simple proof one can use indicator random variables.

Comment: I think the approach using Vandermonde is the simplest.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Could you please elaborate? My understanding is that per each ball, one assigns an indicator r.v., which is 1 is the ball is picked in the sample, and 0 otherwise. Did I get it right?

Comment: @M.S.Dousti: It is short, but I will write it out.

Answer (score 2):

If we are looking to evaluate

$$\sum_{q=0}^k q{m\choose q}{n\choose k-q}
= \sum_{q=1}^k q{m\choose q}{n\choose k-q}
= m \sum_{q=1}^k {m-1\choose q-1}{n\choose k-q}$$

there is a very simple proof using the integral representation

$${n\choose k-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k-q+1}} (1+z)^n
\; dz.$$

This is zero when $q\gt k$ so we may extend the sum to infinity to get

$$\frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^n
\sum_{q\ge 1} {m-1\choose q-1} z^q
\; dz
\\ = \frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^n
z (1+z)^{m-1}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k}} (1+z)^{m+n-1}
\; dz.$$

This is

$$m{m+n-1\choose k-1}
= \frac{km}{m+n} {m+n\choose k}.$$

Comment: +1. This answer taught me a lot, thanks! But I'll wait to see if a more "elementary" answer shows up.

Answer (score 2):

For $i=1$ to $k$, define the indicator random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th ball picked is white, and by $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $W$ of white balls picked is given by
$$W=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_k.$$
By the *linearity of expectation*, we have 
$$E(W)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots+E(X_k).\tag{1}$$
For any $i$, the probability that the $i$-th ball picked is white is $\frac{m}{m+n}$. This is because any ball is just as likely as any other to be the obe picked $i$-th.

Thus $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{m}{n}$, and therefore $E(X_i)=\frac{m}{m+n}$. It follows from (1) that $E(W)=k\cdot \frac{m}{m+n}$.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. I assume this corresponds to (and further formalizes) counting method 1 in the question, right?

Comment: You are welcome. One can think of it as a formal version of your first argument, with a proof of unbiasedness thrown in.  Here the sampling is without replacement, but the very nice thing about linearity of expectation is that it does not require independence (the $X_i$ are not independent).

Comment: Great. I always *loved* your answers; they're so inspiring!